# Python Pip install error with: flask-mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask, pip

I am using Python 3.5+ on Windows 10 (X64bit) PC. I was trying to install MySQLdb with pip .
Here in command

```
pip install flask-mysqldb
```

But it show me an error

> Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Then i installed this software and try again but show me same problem.

> visual c++ 2008 express edition with sp1

Also i checked other solution in stackoverflow,but cant fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you are using python 3.x.

I think the problem is of some registry settings as you are getting Visual studio problems.

Here are the workaround steps:

1. Reinstall python. This will set the missing registry.
2. Then run the below command

   `pip install mysqlclient`

Edited : **MySQLdb** does not support Python 3 but it is not the only MySQL driver for Python. You can install `mysql client` using above command.